# How can we take inputs in C language without using scanf function

Tags: c

I want to take an input in C language but it should be without the use of scanf function. So how can it be done?

Comment: `fgets` is one possibility.

Comment: [C input/output functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) may help

Comment: `fscanf()`, `vfscanf()`, `fgetc()`, `fgets()`, `getc()`, `getchar()`, `fread()`, in addition to `scanf()`, are standard C library functions that can take input from `stdin`.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` is almost always the best choice for reading input from the command line:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100
...
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0'; // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/27729970
```

From here, you can use string parsing functions on `buffer`, such as `sscanf`, `strtol`, `strtoul`, `strtod`, `strtof`, `strstr`, `strchr`, etc. to parse the string.

One of the main advantages of taking input this way is it gives you greater control over how you populate your program's data with it. For example, if you want to populate a comma-delimited list of integers of unknown length, `scanf` does not give you this level of control:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
size_t cCommas = 0, i;
char *pNext = &buffer[0], *pStop = NULL;
long *longs = NULL;
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';

while (pNext = strchr(pNext, ','))
{
    cCommas++;
    pNext++;
}

longs = malloc((cCommas + 1) * sizeof(long));
if (NULL == longs)
{
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

i = 0;
pNext = buffer;
do
{
    longs[i] = strtol(pNext, &pStop, 10);
    pNext = (pStop + 1);
    i++;
}
while (i <= cCommas);

use(longs);

free(longs);
longs = NULL;
```